# Prove that there are no natural numbers to satisfy the equation.

Tags: number-theory, integers

Prove that there are no natural numbers to satisfy the equation:

$a^2+b^2=3(c^2+d^2)$.

I tried to factorize it:
$a^2 + b^2 - 3 (c^2 + d^2)=0$  but I am not getting anywhere.
I can't think of anything else!!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: do you know the criterion for a number to be the sum of two squares?

Comment: Robert Israel, no. It's been years I haven't done any maths. It must be something with Fermat's theorem, right?